# Why is UTXO model better than Account model?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

According to [this](http://learnmeabitcoin.com/guide/outputs) I infer that UTXO is better (or at least more secure) than Account model.

> The reason why transactions work this way is because it’s an easier and more secure way of doing it from a programming perspective.

Why is that?

Comment: You'd have to ask the person who wrote that article.

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Design-Rationale#accounts-and-not-utxos

Comment: @smarx ok I could, but I chose to come here because I thought it was the general opinion...

Answer (score 0):

I found an intresting artical about it.
https://medium.com/@sunflora98/utxo-vs-account-balance-model-5e6470f4e0cf

Comment: Hi there, link-only answers are discouraged. If the link goes dead or is moved then your answer becomes obsolete. Can you summarise the main points in your answer?